# Where is the Harmonic mean used?

Tags: means

There is a mean called Harmonic mean.
http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.2#E19

I mostly see usage of arithematic mean and geometric mean. On the other hand, I have never seen the usage of Harmonic mean yet.

In what kind of case, is the Harmonic mean used?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Examples).

Comment: @mathlove Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You go on a round trip.  You go out at $50$ miles per hour and come back at $60$ miles per hour.  The average speed of your whole trip will be the harmonic mean of $50$ and $60$ (mph).  You can extend this to several legs of a trip all the same length.  Your overall average speed will be the harmonic mean of the speeds on the various legs of the trip.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your reply is very simple to understand for me.

Answer (score 1):

The harmonic mean usually appears when averaging speed (or rates in general).

See this question as a reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794664/how-should-i-calculate-the-average-speed-by-road-segment-for-multiple-segments/34795821#34795821